# failure to verify truffle compiled contract on ropsten.etherscan.io

Tags: truffle, etherscan, verify, contract-verification, truffle-compile

Recently just pushed my first smart contract from `truffle` to the `ropsten` testnet.

As you can see from my terminal output below it compiles and was migrated with no problem:

[image]

Was broadcast to the network by my running `geth` node:

[image]

The contract can be found on my [GitHub here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/solidificateur/blob/master/contracts/Incrementer.sol), it looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

// This contract demonstrates a simple non-constant (transactional) function you can call from geth.
// increment() takes no parameters and merely increments the "iteration" value. 

contract Incrementer {
    uint iteration;

    function Incrementer() {
        iteration = 0;
    }

    function increment(uint count) {
        iteration += count;
    }

    function getIteration() constant returns (uint) {
        return iteration;
    }

}
```

This is the [representation of the transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x267e3ad48c789b29bc9fa4ef254daa13573f79c32f28cb9ef5098291088f65c2) on `ropsten.etherscan.io`:

[image]

You can see that the `ByteCode on the Blockchain (what we are looking for)` and the `Your Compiled Bytecode (what you provided)` are the same in the beginning- I don't know if that means anything or not- but anyhow:

[image]

I know that in the past there were some problems with trying to verify contracts compiled with `truffle` with respect to the `Runs (Optimizer)`, but so far as I could tell this has been fixed, anyway for good measure I've tried to verify with this value set to `0` and also to `200`, neither have worked...

Here's what I've been entering:

Is it correct what I've been doing?

[image]

Why is this contract not verifying?

Comment: Did you select the same compiler version for compilation and verification. Truffle usually uses the latest stable version of the compiler while on the screenshot I looks like you took the latest commit for verification. So probably this results in different bytecode and verification fails. Anyways I would just use the contract and treat it as verified if it works as expected.

Comment: That might be it, I was selecting the compiler I declared in my code

Comment: man I don't think that's it, I've just tried every compiler `0.4.13` and above, none of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to verify the "Migrations" contract that you used in your truffle configuration.

You incrementer contract was the next contract you created, and can be found here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8705c513da621a16fd1defc9de8ae7cdead01fb8#code

I verified it for you, using the Optimizer but setting it to 0 optimizations. You were using 0.4.13, as expected.