# Is there a way to unit test Solidity contracts without running ethereum node?

Tags: solidity, unittesting

I don't want to run an ethereum node on my local machine, but for my project I need to tests solidity contracts. Are there any tools that allow such thing?

Comment: You can use [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) or deploy an isolated private test network.

Comment: Yes, that seems like what I'm looking for. I will try this and let people know how it goes. I will probably use truffle for tests alongside testrpc. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to run a node at least locally, but I think private chains are what you're looking for.  Basically you just run a private chain on your local computer (create your own chain) and then mine that chain so it processes transactions (your contracts).

Check [this](https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/), its a great tutorial to get started on Ubuntu.

You can also use a test chain and get test ethers through a faucet.  I use Ropsten and it works well.  Technically you'll be running a node and it might take a little to sync but then you can deploy contracts on an actual network.

Cheers

Comment: I would rather use something a bit more light weight like testrpc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to unit test Solidity contractswithout running ethereum node? I don't want to run an ethereum node on my local machine

Since your Question is to test smart contract without running in a node, suggesting to have a private network is not the answer, although its a good way to test smart Contracts. And as mentioned in @jojeyh's answer

> You have to run a node at least locally

I don't think its necessary for you to have a node running.

**With [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.js)**, the browser IDE of solidity, You have two options for this.

1. Use Injected web3 with a service like [metamask](https://metamask.io/) (you have to install the [browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn)) and connect to a test network.
2. Use JavaScript VM to test smart contracts without actually deploying it to a network.

All what you have to do is to select the environment to be JavaScriptVM or InjectedWeb3.

[image]

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11495/best-way-to-test-a-smart-contract) might also be useful to you.

**OR With [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc)**

What you are looking for is not the browser based one, you can always use [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) as @ismael mentioned in a comment. And as mentioned in there github repo they use EthereumJS to simulate  fullnode behavior hence your goal is achieved.

> testrpc is a Node.js based Ethereum client for testing and
> development. It uses ethereumjs to simulate full client behavior and
> make developing Ethereum applications much faster. It also includes
> all popular RPC functions and features (like events) and can be run
> deterministically to make development a breeze.

**OR**

if you want to setup a private node as suggested by some others, refer [go-ethereum github wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster) at first. but in this case you are running a node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would rather avoid using web interfaces as I need something a bit more lower level for my project, but this will be my second option. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mention it since it was in @ismael 's comment. I'll add that to answer