# Ethereum Solidity smart contract code Input Output Testing

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have written a solidity based smart contract. I need to test the code on web browser and mobile app. Please suggest the steps what I should do to test and execute the code on -

1. Web browser:- I am aware about Mocha and Metamask but do not know
   how to interface the smart contract code to be tested on Mocha or
   Metamask. Any pointers or tutorials are well appreciated.
2. Mobile App:- What and how should I execute the smart contract code
   on Mobile App. Any pointers or tutorials are well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are developing a Dapp and trying to test it. I think, the two parts of a Dapp smart contract and the Interface for the users should be tested separately. So first you can test the smart contract using remix IDE or test rpc. see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/is-there-a-way-to-unit-test-solidity-contracts-without-running-ethereum-node) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11495/best-way-to-test-a-smart-contract).

The interfaces like web or mobile will communicate with smart contract via a package like web3js for example in node. Those interactions will just be like external API calls. Hence those can be tested as you test normal web app or a mobile app.